# Laravel - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to add FK 'module_id' to my table 'documents'. I have ran the following query:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('documents', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->integer('module_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('module_id')->references('id')->on('modules');

        });
    }
```

The following error is being returned:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
>   (SQL: alter table `documents` add constraint
>   `documents_module_id_foreign` foreign key (`module_id`) references
>   `modules` (`id`))

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I'm sure it is probably a silly mistake but I have spent a lot of time going around in circles trying to figure it out... here is what I have tried..

- both tables are already created
- the data types for both column's are consistent (both unsignedBigInts, 20)

I have included a picture of my DB tables, i appreciate any help.
[image]
[image]

Update:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`laravel`.`#sql-2cd_23`, CONSTRAINT `documents_module_id_foreign`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`module_id`) REFERENCES `modules` (`id`)) (SQL: alter
>   table `documents` add constraint `documents_module_id_foreign` foreign
>   key (`module_id`) references `modules` (`id`))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the column needs to be a big integer.

```
    Schema::table('documents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('module_id');
        $table->foreign('module_id')->references('id')->on('modules');

    });
```

**Update**

You probably already got data in your tables, since the column can't be null the foreign key can't exists. Starting it out as nullable then adding the relationships and removing the nullable would fix it. So:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('module_id')->nullable();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this.. i made the changes but produced an error (I've attached in my original qs... could you advise?

Comment: Thank you! I deleted the data (wasn't relatively important) and it worked. Appreciate it